# Keyboard not dismissing when UIAlertView with textfields is dismissed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Ok, so I've got a view controller that is being displayed one of two ways:

1. Through a storyboard segue
2. Manually via [MyViewController presentViewController:].

Basically, it's a settings view that can be shown via navigating to the settings section of the app or shown on demand if the user needs to input something into the view.

In the settings view, I have a UIAlertView that pops up with a username and password style alert. The first text field is set to firstResponder and the keyboard appears as normal. If I dismiss the alert (via cancel or any other button) the keyboard disappears.

Now, for the issue:
If I show the view controller through the segue, everything works properly. 
If I show it manually, the keyboard will never dismiss no matter what I do.

I've tried setting another view as first responder then resigning, that doesn't help. 
I've tried calling [self.view endEditing:YES] but that doesn't help. 
I've sent a global resignFirstResponder via:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

but that doesn't help. 
I've even hooked up a private API to get the first responder, but it reported the first responder as (null).

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance on sample code? I tried reproducing it and could not get the keyboard to not dismiss.

Comment: if you dimiss the alertview the keyboard will go away, check your alertview has its delegate set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make sure to show the alert late in the view life cycle of the view controller that's presenting it, e.g.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showTheAlert) afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)showTheAlert {
    // alloc, init and show the alert here
}
```

And I'd use a delegate callback to give the textView first responder, e.g.

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [theUsernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And I'd use the delegate for any dismissal to resign.  There's no downside to resigning first responder on a text field that isn't the first responder, so just resign both.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    [theUsernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [thePasswordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This resolved the issue- apparently I was showing the alert view too soon, so I guess the delegate wasn't getting called properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can conform self as a delegate of your UIAlertView once you create one. After that in:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

method you can get reference to your text field and you can call resignFirstResponder on it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
      UITextField *txtField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:buttonIndex];
      [txtField resignFirstResponder];
}
```